# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing beginFileUpload

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I am trying to submit the **ExclamationTopology** example found in storm-start to a single node cluster and getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing beginFileUpload
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitJarAs(StormSubmitter.java:507)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyInDistributeMode(StormSubmitter.java:332)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:274)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:206)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:169)
at ExclamationTopology.main(ExclamationTopology.java:85)
Caused by: org.apache.storm.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing beginFileUpload
at org.apache.storm.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79)
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_beginFileUpload(Nimbus.java:1035)
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.beginFileUpload(Nimbus.java:1023)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitJarAs(StormSubmitter.java:476)
```

My environment:

- Linuxmint-19.1 (64bit)
- Apache-storm-2.1.0
- Apache-zookeeper-3.5.5

Answer (score 2):

Do you have nimbus logs for your case?

Sometimes there is useful information on this kind of error messages. Look for

> No available slots for topology:

In my case I had to remove corrupt topologies with a storm admin command called

> storm admin remove_corrupt_topologies

Maybe this helps in your case!